# Hibernate mapping doesn't allow null timestamp

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, hbm

I am developing a web based application using spring-hibernate combination with Mysql as a database. I have observed 1 problem with hibernate mapping that it doesn't allow me to set null, when type is timestamp. Here is code snippet for better understanding

Here my agenda is - I want to allow user to enter null value for endTime, not for stTime.

`schedule.htm.xml`

```
<id
    name="id"
    type="long"
    column="test_run_schedule_id" 
>
    <generator class="increment" />
</id>

<property
    name="testName"
    type="java.lang.String"
    column="test_run_name"
    not-null="true"
    length="45"
/>
<property
    name="operation"
    type="java.lang.String"
    column="operation_included"
    not-null="true"
    length="500"
/>
<property
    name="stTime"
    type="java.util.Date"
    column="start_time"
    not-null="true"
    length="19"
/>

<property
    name="endTime"
    type="java.util.Date"
    column="end_time"
    not-null="false"
    length="19"
/>
```

When I looked into Mysql database, it showing me Columns `start_time [timestamp, NOTNULL]`,  as well as `end_time [timestamp, NOTNULL]` instead of `end_time[timestamp, NULL]`.

So when I insert value, `end_time` is always taken as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` by default.

How do I create a NULLABLE `end_time` column?

Comment: How do you generate your database schema? Have you re-generated it after setting the not-null attribute to false?

Comment: How was your DDL created? Perhaps you created it with `not-null="true"` and it was not updated after your modifications? If so, consider using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` or `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` (this will delete tables on session close). Also have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties)